# Burning a mpg file(audio+video) to DVD to view in a DVD player

Tags: dvd, mpg

I have a *.mpg file. This file i can play back in [VLC player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/).

I want to burn this mpg file to a DVD, so as to view it on my TV using my DVD player.

If i just burn this mpg file, to a DVD as data dvd, will this serve my purpose?

Or

If not, then what is the process to achieve what i am looking to do?

thanks

-AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes burning it as a data DVD should suffice. It really depends on your DVD player and if it has the ability to decode such a file.

**Edit**, it works for me on my DVD player.

Answer (score 1):

For best results you want something like [Easy CD DVD Burner](http://download.cnet.com/Free-Easy-CD-DVD-Burner/3000-2646_4-10627009.html).

> Free and easy CD & DVD burning solution. Burn data, audio, video to your CDs & DVDs is now very easy. Audio format supported : WAV, WMA, MP3, OGG, FLAC, AAC, M4A. Burn and save ISO files, copy your DVDs. Burn your dvd-video. Save your favorite audio CDs to mp3 with the internal grabber. Support for dual-layer DVD, CD-R, CD-RW, DVD-R, DVD+R, DVD-RW, DVD+RW. Standard ISO9660 & Joliet, buffer UnderRun protection, and Multisession support. Version 3.9 is a bug fixing release.

There are plenty of others. A search for "free dvd burner" on Google gives a lot of results. You might want to check them out before installing though - to double check they do what you want.

Comment: To add to this, DVD players won't be able to read data DVDs, it has to be converted to how normal DVDs are made. So, in order to achieve this, you have to do what ChrisF has mentioned.

Comment: @Steven Lu: "normal" (video) DVDs *are* just data DVDs -- with files in particular formats and places.

Answer (score 1):

In order to qualify as DVD-Video, the MPEG-2 must have specific pixel dimensions, bitrate, and other technical attributes, which differ if the player is NTSC or PAL. One peculiarity is that neither use square pixels -- so if the video does *not* looked squished or squashed on a (naive) computer-based player, it's unlikely to be strictly valid.

A newer DVD player might play "any old" MPEG file simply burned to disc, but for universality it must be genuine DVD-Video. (An older player might also have problems playing a burned DVD.)

If you use DVD authoring software, it will likely convert any video it accepts into a valid form, which requires re-encoding, taking time and reducing video quality.